# Add query web part to display form to show related items in another list?

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, display-form, joined-view

I have a list which contains information that is heavily linked with info in another list. The most similar example that I've seen was where someone had a list of customers and then a total list of orders. What I would be attempting to do is add a webpart to the customer list's display form to show all the customer's orders in the other list (e.g., where customer name in order's = customer name in current item).

Is this possible to do dynamically without hindering performance too much (5000 items in other list)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by SharePoint Designer.

- Add a lookup column to the Orders list, which will refer to the Customers list
- Open Customers list in SharePoint Designer
- Edit Customers Display Form, from the toolbar, select Insert a "Related Item View", your Orders list should show up in the option list, choose it
- Add/Remove columns of the Orders view

You need to put the Orders list's reference column to the Customers list as **Indexed column**, and other columns like "Product", "Order date" etc as index columns and sort your Orders view by those indexed columns. That will make you safe with the 5,000 records throttling.

Comment: edit: Actually, I don't have the option of making the fields "look up" which I believe is the key in being able to use this "Related Item View" - Is there another way of matching two field values (e.g., show me all items in the sub list where these 2 fields match 2 fields in the current item) ?

Comment: You have 2 ways to get away from the throttling: 1.Use folders; 2.Use Indexed Columns (and be sure that you have at lease one filter in your view uses an indexed column). These 2 ways will change the way a SharePoint View looking for data with reduced records to be scanned, thus can avoid the throttling. Indexed column values will not be affected, they will stay in regular format.

Comment: Another workaround without lookup fields, will be using the Query String parameter. You need somehow manage to add Customer ID into your Orders list items, then use the Query String of Customer DispForm.aspx to filter the Order List View. It's a long story and I can't find good reference from the internet. Maybe I'll write one and then post you a link here.

Comment: I actually managed to do this, but my issue is that I don't have a unique value in my Customer list. Unfortunately, my unique selector is a combination of two fields rather than one (e.g., Where Area = Area and Manager = Manager instead of ID = CustID). The "Get Filter Values From" option is only working with ID, Title, and a simple "Yes/No" column for some reason.

Comment: You can use a Calculated Column to join Area & Manager into a new column then use the new one for filtering.

Comment: You can't change an existing column into a Lookup column; Lookup columns can only be newly-created columns.

Comment: FWIW, I wasn't trying to change an existing field type to "lookup", but you can edit certain field types to lookps with csom/jsom.
I just meant that I wasn't in a position to create new lookup fields to replace the old ones.